# Selenium code for Video click in iFrame works in Debug but fails in normal,tried sleep,wait etc

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, iframe, junit

The code below works as expected in debug mode of Eclipse, but when  try Normal mode, I get the error below. I even increased `thread.sleep` from `3000` to `12000` but still fails at Normal mode.

In debug mode, when I put a breakpoint at line 45 and 46 and step over them, the Video plays.

```
/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest  extends TestCase
{    
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Sprints//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://Sprints//geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64//geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://utubehits.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys("wealthytarundas2015@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("Tapan@321");
        driver.findElement(By.name("connect")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("YouTube Views")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Watch Video")).click();

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        //driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
        List<WebElement> frameElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='iframe']"));

        //--------- HERE I PUT BREAK POINT ----------
        System.out.println(frameElements.size());

        //........ HERE I PUT BREAK POINT ----------
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='ytPlayer']")));

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")).click();

    }
}
```

**Error that appears in the console:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 7753
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 29, 2017 3:54:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
UtubeHits.com - YouTube Exchange Website
1
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe[id='ytPlayer']"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'TDAS-PK', ip: '10.239.31.215', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a), userDataDir=C:\Users\prokarma\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4672_687}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=61.0.3163.100, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: c128094673a6b33419aebb2bbea0e7b6
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=iframe[id='ytPlayer']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:450)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at basic.basic.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:49)
```

Comment: Put a sleep before `List<WebElement> frameElements = driver.findElements` and see if that fixes your issue. Most probably you are trying to find frame too early

Comment: The credentials you provided login/pass are not working, do you have a set of working dummy credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep(4000);

    driver.switchTo().frame("iframe").switchTo().frame("ytPlayer");

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using sleep to wait for the element, try using an explicit WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions to repeatedly poll the DOM for your desired state.

I've updated your example below:

```
/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest  extends TestCase
{    
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Sprints//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://Sprints//geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64//geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://utubehits.com/");

        //This is the magic thing. It will repoll the dom for 25 seconds before it gives up.
        WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);

        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("login"))).sendKeys("wealthytarundas2015@gmail.com");
        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("pass"))).sendKeys("Tapan@321");
        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("connect"))).click();
        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("YouTube Views"))).click();
        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Watch Video"))).click();

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        //driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
        List<WebElement> frameElements = explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='iframe']")));

        //--------- HERE I PUT BREAK POINT ----------
        System.out.println(frameElements.size());

        //........ HERE I PUT BREAK POINT ----------            
       //I'm not certain I have this exactly right, you may have to fiddle with it a bit
        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='ytPlayer']")));

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        explicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']"))).click();

    }
}
```

Using explicit waits in combination with setting the implicit waits can help to account for many timing conditions various browsers experience during testing.

Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks you ,this got working by making below code change,definitely i will keep in mind above tips for my next automation task